# How would you show that $\sqrt{14+4\sqrt{10}} - \sqrt{14-4\sqrt{10}} = 4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I've recently seen a Highschool problem and I was wondering, how would you show that

$$\sqrt{14+4\sqrt{10}} - \sqrt{14-4\sqrt{10}} = 4$$

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Note that both numbers are positive, so the equality is true if, and only if its squares are equal. Proceed from there.

Comment: $14 = 2^2 + \sqrt{10}^2$

Comment: Give your questions a title which makes it easy for people with similar problems to find your question.

Answer (score 9):

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{14+4\sqrt{10}} - \sqrt{14-4\sqrt{10}} &= \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{14+4\sqrt{10}} - \sqrt{14-4\sqrt{10}}\right)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{14 + 4\sqrt{10} + 14 - 4\sqrt{10} - 2\sqrt{(14 + 4\sqrt{10})(14-4\sqrt{10})}} \\
&= \sqrt{28 - 2\sqrt{14^2 - 4^2\cdot 10}} \\
&= \sqrt{28 - 2\cdot \sqrt{196 - 160}} \\
&= \sqrt{28 - 2\sqrt{36}} \\
&= \sqrt{28 - 12} \\
&= \sqrt{16} \\
&= 4\end{align}$$

In the above, you're applying $(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab$ and $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative way note that $$\eqalign{\sqrt{14+4\sqrt{10}} - \sqrt{14-4\sqrt{10}} &= \sqrt{\sqrt{10}^2+2\cdot2\sqrt{10}+2^2} - \sqrt{\sqrt{10}^2-2\cdot2\sqrt{10}+2^2}},$$ then use the identity $a^2\pm2ab+b^2=(a\pm b)^2$, and simplify.

Comment: Nice. One could also prove first that (for $0<b<a$) this is true: 
$ \sqrt{a + b +- 2\sqrt a \sqrt b} = \sqrt a +- \sqrt b $ and then use it with $a=10$ and $b=4$

Comment: @ypercube Yes, thanks for citing the generalization of this solution.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt{ 14 \pm 4 \sqrt{10}} = \sqrt{10} \pm 2 $$
since $\sqrt{10} \pm 2>0 $ and $(\sqrt{10} \pm 2)^2 =  14 \pm 4 \sqrt{10} $.

Answer (score 3):

This was quite easy sum , here I used the general solution for (a+2b^1/2)^1/2=x^1/2 +y^1/2
 [image: very easy sum]

Comment: Isn't this the simplest method?

Answer (score 2):

Both numbers are positive, so the equality is true if, and only if its squares are equal. By squaring both sides we get

$$14+4\sqrt{10}-2\sqrt{(14+4\sqrt10)(14-4\sqrt{10})}+14-4\sqrt{10} = 4^2$$

$$14-2\sqrt{(14^2-16 \cdot 10)}+14 = 16$$

$$28-12 = 16$$

$$16 = 16$$

Comment: In general if you're asked to show LHS = RHS, it's better to manipulate from one side to the other, e.g. LHS = something = something = ... = RHS. Rather than working on both sides at the same time.

Comment: @Deepak I disagree. It is not always easy to see how to do that, and can be made easier by manipulating both sides until you see how they can connect. And often you will add/subtract or multiply both sides by something, in which case you are automatically manipulating both expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\sqrt{14+4\sqrt{10}}=a, \sqrt{14-4\sqrt{10}}=b$, then
$$a^2+b^2=28, ab=6$$
So $(a-b)^2=16$ and $a-b=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $14+4\sqrt{10}\gt14-4\sqrt{10}\gt0$, the difference of the square roots is equal to something positive, i.e.,

$$\sqrt{14+4\sqrt{10}}-\sqrt{14-4\sqrt{10}}=u\gt0$$

If we square both sides, we have

$$\begin{align}
u^2&=(14+4\sqrt{10})-2\sqrt{14+4\sqrt{10}}\sqrt{14-4\sqrt{10}}+(14-4\sqrt{10})\\
&=28-2\sqrt{14^2-4^2\cdot10}\\
&=28-2\sqrt{36}\\
&=16
\end{align}$$

Since $u\gt0$ was already established, we can conclude $u=4$.